# How to send multiple parameters in a function using EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to do some on page form submissions. When a users ticks a checkbox, it marks their attendance for a class for a certain week by submitting a form using onclick() to call a function to submit the correct form. There can be up to 8 students in each class and each student will have 6 check boxes. The forms are identified by the Id of the student and a number from the loop of each weeks class. 

The issue I am having is that when I try to send those 2 identifying EJS variables as parameters to the submit function, the function never gets called.

I have tried only sending 1 parameter and it works fine. I need both parameters in order to be able to make this work properly. Without them, certain checkboxes will try to submit other forms and it breaks the app.

```
<% foundClass.students.forEach(function(foundStudent){ %>
  <tr>
     <% for(let i=0; i < foundStudent.attendance.length; i++){ %>
        <td>
           <form id="attendanceCheckbox<%= foundStudent._id %><%= i %>" action="/dashboard/class/<%= foundClass.title %>/<%= foundClass.date %>/attendance/<%= foundStudent._id %>/<%= i %>" method="post">
             <% if(foundStudent.attendance[i] === true){ %>
               <input class="form-check-input m-0" type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="attendance" value="false" onclick="attendanceSubmit(<%= foundStudent._id %>, <%= i %>)" checked>
             <% } else { %>
               <input class="form-check-input m-0" type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="attendance" value="true" onclick="attendanceSubmit(<%= foundStudent._id %>, <%= i %>)">
             <% } %>
           </form>
        </td>
     <% } %>
  <tr>
<% } %>


<script>
    function attendanceSubmit(studentId, classNumber){
        document.getElementById('attendanceCheckbox' + studentId + classNumber).submit();
    }
</script>
```

Here's the solution I found: 
Each EJS variable must be wrapped in quotation marks.
`onclick='attendanceSubmit("<%= foundStudent._id %>", "<%= i %>")'`
I used single quotes for the quotations for defining the onclick action. Each parameter being passed into the function must also be surrounded by quotations, so double quotes must be used for those.

Comment: When the page is rendered and if you right click on one input and select "inspect", what is showing you inside onclick?

Comment: @razielx4crazy it shows `attendanceSubmit(0)` for the first, `attendanceSubmit(1)` for the second and continues 4 more times for each input. It completely ignores the first parameter. however, this ejs variable does work fine being used in the form's id name.

Comment: Are you sure it is working fine in form id? Can you click on inspect and tell me what you see? I'm not sure why you put <form id="attendanceCheckbox<%= foundStudent._id %><%= i %>"

Comment: @razielx4crazy `<form id="attendanceCheckbox5d561986bf210a105c51a8651" action="/dashboard/class/odor/2019-02-03-18:30/attendance/5d561986bf210a105c51a865/1" method="post">
                            
                                <input class="form-check-input m-0" type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="attendance" value="false" onclick="attendanceSubmit(5d561986bf210a105c51a865, 1)" checked>
                            
                        </form>
` is what shows up. I put the form ID so that javascript can submit the correct form. The ._id and the i are identifiers

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out! You should answer your own question in an actual answer, instead of posting it in the question.

Comment: Post your answer below as an answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I found: Each EJS variable must be wrapped in quotation marks. onclick='attendanceSubmit("<%= foundStudent._id %>", "<%= i %>")' I used single quotes for the quotations for defining the onclick action. Each parameter being passed into the function must also be surrounded by quotations, so double quotes must be used for those.